# How to get data for the last week data?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a report whereby the report will have the contract updated records for the past week using ms sql script. Every Monday the report will be sent for the last Mon-sun. I tried the below query. it doesnt seems to work. Any idea how to achieve this?

```
SET DATEFIRST 1

select distinct [...]
where CONTRACT_UPDATE_DATE>= dateadd(day, 1-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate())) 
AND CONTRACT_UPDATE_DATE<  dateadd(day, 8-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate()))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from table_abc WHERE
CAST(CONTRACT_UPDATE_DATE as date) between 
CAST(DATEADD(dd, -7, GETDATE()) as date) and
CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

use `dateadd` to get 1 week before current date.

You can remove the cast as date if you need to validate by timestamp also.

Comment: In this method, i am getting records fetched for today(Mon) also. My report should have only last Mon-Sun records.For ex:27 march to 2nd April

Comment: I changed it to '>' instead of '>=' , Could you check again? @LT268

Comment: No..it's still the same issue before. Today's record also capturing :(

Comment: Thanks Bennjoe.. In the given code also the current date records were fetched. So i modified your query slightly to adjust my requirement. It works now.

Comment: select distinct ... where CAST(ch.CONTRACT_UPDATE_DATE_LT as date) between 
CAST(DATEADD(dd, -8, GETDATE()) as date) and
CAST(DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE()) as date)- I used this

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

```
SELECT Created_Date
FROM sample1
WHERE Created_Date >= DATEADD(day,-11117, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this solution:

```
 select * from DB where Datediff(day, CONVERT(DATE, Sysdatetime()), 
                                 CONVERT(DATE, CONTRACT_UPDATE_DATE))<=7 and  Datediff(day, CONVERT(DATE, Sysdatetime()), 
                                 CONVERT(DATE, CONTRACT_UPDATE_DATE))>0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to achieve this by using the calender week.
Try the following:

```
-- Get last calendar week in format JJJJWW
DECLARE @jjjjkw varchar(6)
SELECT @jjjjkw =
CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(YYYY,GETDATE()-7)) + 
CASE WHEN LEN(CONVERT(varchar,DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,GETDATE()-7))) = 1 THEN '0'
+ CONVERT(varchar,DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,GETDATE()-7))
ELSE CONVERT(varchar,DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,GETDATE()-7)) END

-- Compare with the calendar week of your data-set
SELECT DISTINCT [...]
WHERE   
CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(YYYY,CONTRACT_UPDATE_DATE)) + 
CASE WHEN LEN(CONVERT(varchar,DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,CONTRACT_UPDATE_DATE))) = 1
THEN '0' + CONVERT(varchar,DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,CONTRACT_UPDATE_DATE))
ELSE CONVERT(varchar,DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,CONTRACT_UPDATE_DATE)) END = @jjjjkw
```

Maybe not the most elegant way but it should work.