# How to query date in SQL for data in the last week

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

My current query is:

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Previous_Appointment WHERE`apDate`BETWEEN '2017-04-03'  AND '2017-04-27'`

I need this to run however to just check today's date -7 days, -30 days, etc... 
So that it returns the number of instances that have occured.

Comment: Tag your database you are using.

Comment: Are you using MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQL Server, etc.?

Comment: I updated the tag, mysql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get data for the last week data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43177209/how-to-get-data-for-the-last-week-data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

Between today and today -7

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Previous_Appointment WHERE DATE(apDate) > (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Between today and today -30

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Previous_Appointment WHERE DATE(apDate) > (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use dateadd -7 days

```
dateadd(day,-7,cast(getdate() as date))
```

Answer (score 1):

To get count in last week:

```
select count(*)
from previous_appointment
where apDate between curdate() - interval 7 day and curdate()
```

To get count in last 30 days:

```
select count(*)
from previous_appointment
where apDate between curdate() - interval 30 day and curdate()
```